# How to change CupertinoDatePicker dateFormat?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

As you can see the dateFormat of `CupertinoDatePicker` is year month day.

But I want show year and month only.

How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 500,
  height: 250,
  child: CupertinoDatePicker(
    mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
    dateOrder: DatePickerDateOrder.ymd,
    onDateTimeChanged: (date) {
      print(date);
    },
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide it directly as there is no such method for hiding it. But what you can do is go to the `'/Users/your_user_name/developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/date_picker.dart'` and copy the complete code from that file. Now go to your project directory and create a new dart file with anyName.dart and paste the whole code there. And search for the below Text widget in the file.

```
          Text(
              localizations.datePickerDayOfMonth(day),
              style:
                  _themeTextStyle(context, isValid: day <= daysInCurrentMonth),
            ),
```

Here replace the `localizations.datePickerDayOfMonth(day)` with empty string ' ' like that.
Then where you need to use the customed Picker call it like:

```
import 'package:local_app/ui/widgets/anyName.dart' as customizedDatePicker;
```

and use it

```
  customizedDatePicker.CupertinoDatePicker(
   
    initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
    mode: customizedDatePicker.CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use [**`flutter_cupertino_date_picker`**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_date_picker) and  [**`flutter_cupertino_datetime_picker`**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupertino_datetime_picker)hope this is help to you.

```
DatePicker.showDatePicker(
    context,
    maxDateTime: DateTime.now(),
    dateFormat:'yyyy-MMMM'//your expected date format
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CupertinoDatePicker(
          mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
          onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime value) {
            // handle changes to the selected date
          },
          dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy', // specify the date format
        );
```

Here are some examples of formatting symbols that you can use in the dateFormat string:

- d: The day of the month, as a single digit or double digit number
  (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 11, 12, etc.).
- dd: The day of the month, as a double digit number (e.g. 01, 02, 03,
  11, 12, etc.).
- ddd: The abbreviated name of the day of the week (e.g. Sun, Mon, Tue,
  etc.).
- dddd: The full name of the day of the week (e.g. Sunday, Monday,
  Tuesday, etc.).
- M: The month as a single digit or double digit number (e.g. 1, 2, 3,
  11, 12, etc.).
- MM: The month as a double digit number (e.g. 01, 02, 03, 11, 12,
  etc.).
- MMM: The abbreviated name of the month (e.g. Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.).
- MMMM: The full name of the month (e.g. January, February, March,
  etc.).
- y: The year as a two-digit number (e.g. 20, 21, etc.).
- yy: The year as a two-digit number (e.g. 20, 21, etc.).
- yyyy: The year as a four-digit number (e.g. 2020, 2021, etc.).

date formats:

1. 'dd/MM/yyyy': '01/01/2021' (1st January 2021)
2. 'dddd, MMMM d, yyyy': 'Monday, January 4, 2021' (4th January 2021)
3. 'MM/dd/yy': '01/04/21' (4th January 2021)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

copy the code from [URL](https://github.com/rohitchaurasiya151/my_flutter_widget/blob/main/r%26d.dart) and save it anywhere in the lib. use code

```
CustomCupertinoDatePicker(
            mode: CustomCupertinoDatePickerMode.yearAndMonth,
            dateOrder: DatePickerDateOrder.dmy,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
            onDateTimeChanged: (date) {
              print(date);
            },
          )
```